# Key combination input and special key buttons pressing

Tags: c#, keypress, keycode, dotnetbrowser

In the docs only using of 'TAB' button is mentioned.

```
KeyParams paramers = new KeyParams(VirtualKeyCode.TAB, ' ');
```

KeyParams require char representation of the button. So how can it be done right for special 'Control' button?

```
KeyParams paramers = new KeyParams(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, ' ');
```

Am I right that this code would produce key combination Ctrl+A?

```
KeyParams paramers1 = new KeyParams(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, ' ');
KeyParams paramers2 = new KeyParams(VirtualKeyCode.VK_A, 'A');

webView.Browser.KeyDown(paramers1);
webView.Browser.KeyDown(paramers2);

webView.Browser.KeyUp(paramers2);
webView.Browser.KeyUp(paramers1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of the KeyParams class contains the third parameter - `params VirtualKeyCode[] modifiers`.

To simulate pressing `Ctrl + A` you can create the following KeyParams:

`KeyParams p1 = new KeyParams(VirtualKeyCode.VK_A, ' ', VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL);`

And then use the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` methods:

`browser.KeyDown(p1);
 browser.KeyUp(p1);`